# Minitest how to solve mocked method :call expects 0 arguments, got 1

Tags: ruby, mocking, minitest

I have a service with the call method to stub. But its always have this error:

```
SomeTest#test_1:
ArgumentError: mocked method :call expects 0 arguments, got 1
    test.rb:17:in `block in test_1'
    test.rb:16:in `test_1'
```

Here's the code:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

class SomeService
  def initialize(headers = {})
  end

  def call
  end
end

class SomeTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_1
    mock = Minitest::Mock.new
    mock.expect :call, nil

    SomeService.stub :new, mock do
      SomeService.new({}).call
    end
  end
end
```

What did I do wrong? thanks

Answer (score 4):

In general what you wrote is right but you hit and edge case with the method name `call`.

As you can see in the documentation of [stub](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/minitest/4.2.0/Object:stub) method.

"If val_or_callable responds to #call, then it returns the result of calling it".

So basically the problem is your mock responds to `call`, and the `stub` method is calling it before entering the block.
You can solve it by wrapping the mock in a lambda that discards the arguments.

```rb
require 'minitest/autorun'

class SomeService
  def initialize(headers = {})
  end

  def call
  end
end

class SomeTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_1
    mock = Minitest::Mock.new
    mock.expect :call, nil

    SomeService.stub :new, ->(_args) { mock } do
      SomeService.new({}).call
    end
  end
end
```